# Функция перерисовки яндекс карты

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

```js
ymaps.ready(init);
var myMap1,
    myMap2,
    myPlacemark1,
    myPlacemark2,
    myPlacemark3;

function init() {
    myMap1 = new ymaps.Map("map_1", {
        center: [45.04544779, 39.00158981],
        zoom: 11,
        controls: ['zoomControl']
    });
    
myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark([45.02388357, 39.06877350], {
    balloonContentHeader: 'Локация 1',
    balloonContent: 'ул. Сормовская, дом 12/11',
}, {
    iconLayout: 'default#image',
    iconImageClipRect: [[0, 0], [85, 124]],
    iconImageHref: 'img/label_map.png',
    iconImageSize: [33.33, 50],
    iconImageOffset: [-16.66, -50]
});
myPlacemark2 = new ymaps.Placemark([45.03811357, 39.02389400], {
    balloonContentHeader: 'Локация 2',
    balloonContent: 'ул. Школьная, дом 15/6'
}, {
    iconLayout: 'default#image',
    iconImageClipRect: [[85, 0], [170, 124]],
    iconImageHref: 'img/label_map.png',
    iconImageSize: [33.33, 50],
    iconImageOffset: [-16.66, -50]
});
myPlacemark3 = new ymaps.Placemark([45.05108607, 38.93185250], {
    balloonContentHeader: 'Локация 3',
    balloonContent: 'ул. 2-ая линия, дом 49'
}, {
    iconLayout: 'default#image',
    iconImageClipRect: [[170, 0], [255, 124]],
    iconImageHref: 'img/label_map.png',
    iconImageSize: [33.33, 50],
    iconImageOffset: [-16.66, -50]
});
    myMap1.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark1);
    myMap1.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark2);
    myMap1.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark3);

}
//Код кнопки
$('.address-button').click(function () {
    var time = 600;
    //Работает но не перерисовывает
    $('.faq__maps').slideToggle(time);
    //Не работает
//    $('.faq__maps').slideToggle(time, function() {
//       ymaps.myMap1.container.fitToViewport();
//    });
    //Не работает
//    $('.faq__maps').slideToggle(time, function() {
//       ymaps.myMap1.redraw();
//    });
    if ($(this).html() === 'Смотреть на карте') {
        $(this).html('Скрыть карту');
    } else {
        $(this).html('Смотреть на карте');
    }
});
```

```css
.faq__maps{
height: 500px;
background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='address-button'>Скрыть карту</button>
<div class='faq__maps'>
   <div id='map_1' class='mymap'>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

P.S. Пример, почему-то не загружает карту.

Подскажите функцию, на примере, как перерисовать карту? Дело в том, что контейнер карты скрывается функцией JQuery - `.slideToggle()` и когда изменяешь размеры окна, карта подстраивается под размер своего контейнера, а именно под 0. И когда открываешь, карты не видно. Проблема решаема, надо вызвать функцию перерисовки карты. Но ни один из найденных мною вариантов не работает. Я с картами на Вы и вероятно не понимаю синтаксис, помогите.

Пробовал так:
`ymaps.myMap1.container.fitToViewport();`
Пробовал так:
`ymaps.myMap1.redraw();`

Подключен скрипт

https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU

Ничего не работает. Помогите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что у Вас не выставлена высота div блока с картой.
Добавьте её в стили и карта отобразится.

```
.mymap{
height:500px
}
```

Код для перерисовки карты должен быть таким:

```
$('.faq__maps').slideToggle(time, function() {
       myMap1.container.fitToViewport();
    });
```

Вот интерактивный [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/znv2vs5e/).