# Опять функция перерисовки яндекс карты

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Была [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/739493/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B) подобная тема, но ее решение вообще не работает.

```
(function ($, ymaps) {
"use strict";
var maps = new Map();
var counter = 1;
var mapEmpty = '';
$(document).on('onEventToggleOpen', function (e, data) {

    if (data.event.location == '') {
        return;
    }

    var glob = data.glob;
    var $instance = data.$instance;
    var helper = data.helper;

    var event = data.event;
    var $event = $instance.$events.find('.stec-layout-event.active');
    var $inner = $event.find('.stec-layout-event-inner-location');

    $inner.html(function (index, html) {

        return html
                .replace(/stec_replace_location/g, event.location)
                .replace(/stec_replace_map_id/g, event.id)
                .replace(/stec_replace_details/g, event.location_details);
    });

    if ($.trim($inner.find('.stec-layout-event-inner-location-details').text()) == "") {
        $inner.find('.stec-layout-event-inner-location-optional-details').hide();
    }




    function initymap() {
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map-' + event.id, {
            center: [event.latitude, event.longitude],
            zoom: 15,
            autoFitToViewport: 'always'

        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
                // Создаем геообъект с типом геометрии "Точка".
                myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
                    // Описание геометрии.
                    geometry: {
                        type: "Point",
                        coordinates: [event.latitude, event.longitude]
                    },
                    // Свойства.
                    properties: {
                        // Контент метки.
                        iconContent: event.calendar_description,
                        hintContent: event.calendar_description
                    }
                }, {
                    // Опции.
                    // Иконка метки будет растягиваться под размер ее содержимого.
                    preset: 'islands#blackStretchyIcon',
                    // Метку можно перемещать.
                    draggable: true
                });

        myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);
        maps.set('map-' + event.id, myMap);
    }

    function loadMap() {

        if ($inner.is(':visible')) {
            var $event = $inner.parents('.stec-layout-event');


        } else {

            return;
        }

        var $mapCont = $event.find(".stec-layout-event-inner-location-right-gmap");

        // init once
        if ($mapCont.children().length <= 0) {
            var map_cur = 'map-' + event.id;
            counter++;
            ymaps.ready(initymap);
            // initymap;
            console.log(counter + 'create ' + map_cur);
        } else {

            mapEmpty = 'map-' + event.id;
            var time = 600;
            $('.' + mapEmpty).slideToggle(time, function () {
                myMap1 = maps.get(mapEmpty);
                myMap1.container.fitToViewport();
            });
        }

    }

    $(document).on('stec-tab-click-' + glob.options.id, function () {
        loadMap();
    });

    loadMap();

    // Remove preloader
    $inner.find('.stec-layout-event-inner-preload-wrap').children().first().unwrap();
    $inner.find('.stec-layout-event-inner-preload-wrap').remove();
    $inner.find('.stec-preloader').remove();

});})(jQuery, window.ymaps);
```

уже чего только не пробовал и удалял карты и destroy делал и все вместе потом заново создавал. есть адекватный метод который выводит карты из анабиоза?

Так выглядит структура при скрытой карте
[image: Структура при скрытой крте]

А так после ее повторного показа
[image: Повторный показ карты]

Comment: Предоставьте, пожалуйста, пример страницы на которой видно, что не работает. Можно её собрать, например на jsfiddle

Comment: интегрирую карты в готовый плагин в нем порядка 300 файлов приблизительно 300 тыс строк в проекте

Comment: https://cityposter.ru/calendar/ нужно открыть событие посмотреть местоположение, потом другое событие также посмотреть и вернуться к предыдущему событию. Вот тут все и начинается анабиоз в чистом виде.

Comment: Если сможете собрать пример поменьше чем 300 файлов и 300 тыс строк, то было бы замечательно=) Не понимаю зачем все эти сложности с сохранением maps.set и maps.get ? Почему нельзя создавать новую карту при каждом открытии или не удалять контейнер карты после повторного перехода на вкладку? Как в этом примере https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/hiddendiv

Comment: В том то все и дело! Когда не удаляется она перестает шевелиться. вроде кнопки все на месте, но карты нет. И да вы явно не переходили по ссылке cityposter.ru/calendar где можно посмотреть на это добро.

Comment: Контейнер карты удаляется и создается заново в момент раскрытия события. Попробуйте не удалять контейнер или создавать каждый раз карту заново.

Comment: так я скрываю карту когда перехожу на другое событие 
.stec-layout-event-inner {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
в коде она присутствует после скрытия. Когда возвращаться в исходное состояние не хочет показывать географию, остается ее контейнер с кнопками неработающими как будто она не поняла, что ее показали, может ее можно как то оповещать об этом?

Comment: Если вы только скрываете карту и больше ничего, то почему тогда у вас не работает, а в таком примере работает https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/hiddendiv ? Возможно вы делаете, что то ещё?

Comment: Я еще не понял, но вероятно дело в структуре... поправил пост добавил скриншот DevTools

Comment: Посмотрите на тэг с id map-5579 , в момент когда вы открываете событие он удаляется и создаётся заново? Попробуйте удалить $('.' + mapEmpty).slideToggle(time, function () {myMap1 = maps.get(mapEmpty);myMap1.container.fitToViewport();}); это не поможет?

Comment: Да точно удаляется и создается. Вот эту конструкцию удалил, но это не из за нее. Буду смотреть как в плагине реализовано скрытие показ. Спасибо глаза открыли.